# Проблемы с датой в PHP

Tags: php

Браузер отображает следующую пакость

> `Этот текст представляет данные, полученные в результате работы PHP 5: Сегодня Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '6.0/no DST' instead in C:\SERVER\Apache\htdocs\phpstud\simple01.php on line 8`
>
> `Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '6.0/no DST' instead in C:\SERVER\Apache\htdocs\phpstud\simple01.php on line 8`
>
> `Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for '6.0/no DST' instead in C:\SERVER\Apache\htdocs\phpstud\simple01.php on line 8
>     09-23-2011`

Код такой

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Web-страница</title>
</head>
<body>
Этот текст представляет данные, полученные в результате работы PHP 5: Сегодня
<?php
$todaysdate = date("m", time()) . "-" . date("d", time()) . "-" . date("Y", time());
echo $todaysdate;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Где ошибка? Мне кажется, что-то с датой в php, возможно настроить надо.

Comment: вводим в google - date_default_timezone_set() и читаем инфу

Answer (score 2):

Установите временную зону:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$todaysdate = date("d-m-Y", time());
echo $todaysdate; // Виведет 23-09-2011
```

Про буквы, что они значат и какие возможно использовать, посмотрите или в книге, или в инернете - там очень много, как букв времени, так и даты. И изменять можете, как хотите, например, так: `d/m/y` или как у вас `m/d/Y`, это месяц, день и год с четырех знаков.
Эта переменная будет выводить дату ту, что сейчас, если хотите форматировать другую дату, которая имеется, то надо поменять time() на свою переменную.